# Remove GeoJson Colours in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a Map generated using the leafletjs library from GeoJson data, I then colour it therefore making heatmaps, the problem is that I need to clear the colours before I add new colours.

I have found solutions for clearing markers, and that is okay, but I am having trouble with the colours. I know the ChangeMapColour() function in my code currently will paint with the same colours everytime, but don't worry about that, I just need to somehow clear the excising colours form the map. I currently have:

```
Var NUTS2 = ...some GeoJson data....

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.133481, 10.018343], 3);
//var chart = anychart.pie();
<!--add the actual map in the background-->
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=your_token', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.light'
}).addTo(map); 


//add the style function
L.geoJson(NUTS2, {style: style}).addTo(map);
//add what happens at a click on the map
// I do not think the implmentation hereof is important, so omitting
L.geoJSON(NUTS2, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);

//style a spesefic feauture
function style(feature) {
return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.id),
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.1
    };
}

//this function is supposed to clear the colours and add a new one and is called from some button press
function ChangeMapColour()
{
    L.geoJson(NUTS2, {style: style}).addTo(map);
    L.geoJSON(NUTS2, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: you can try to overwrite the style `geojsonlayer.eachLayer(function(layer){layer.setStyle(someStyle);});`

Comment: Ah makes sense, But the problem I am having is (and this may be due to me not understanding the library well enough), is what is the name of the layer I am using. The above code is completely what I have, and here is my attempt at overwriting the style 

  `geojsonlayer.eachLayer(function(layer){
  
  layer.setStyle({
        fillColor: '#800026',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.1
  });
 
 });`

Comment: Where you call `eachLayer()`? Can you make a working jsfiddle? or post you json data

Comment: I get the GeoJson here, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eurostat/Nuts2json/master/2016/4258/20M/nutsrg_2.json 

I copied that over and put it in a variable `var NUTS2 ={...paste geoJson here...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/opt0k6jh/

Add your layer to a featureGroup and then you can clear the group every time and add it new to it with the new color.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
fg.clearLayers();

L.geoJson(data,{style: {fillColor : '#f00'}}).addTo(fg);
```